# Wrong JavaScript Including

Tags: javascript

A main.xhtml page contains:

```
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.actual.min.js"></script>
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

    <!-- smart resize event -->
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.debouncedresize.min.js"></script>
    <!-- js cookie plugin -->
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>
    <!-- js ui -->
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
    <!-- tooltips -->
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/qtip2/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jBreadcrumbs -->
    <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/jBreadcrumbs/js/jquery.jBreadCrumb.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <!-- sticky messages -->
       <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/sticky/sticky.min.js"></script>           
    <!-- common functions -->


     <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


     <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/tinymce/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js"></script>     






<script>
    $.ajax({            
                            type: 'POST',   
                            url: '#{request.contextPath}/view/user/'+ page +'.xhtml',

                            success: function(data) {   
                                $('#main_content').html(data);

                            }   
                        });
<script>
```

As you can see above i can include xhtml pages(like below page) into main.xhtml

Lines from an xhtml page (exact order)

```
    <!-- datatable -->
    <script
        src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script
        src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/datatables/extras/Scroller/media/js/Scroller.min.js"></script>

    <link rel='stylesheet'
        href='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/css/ui.dynatree.css' />

    <!-- validation -->
    <script
        src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/validation/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

    <!-- sticky messages -->
    <script
        src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/lib/sticky/sticky.min.js"></script>

    <script
        src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    <script
        src='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.dynatree.js'
        type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='http://localhost:9090/app/dwr/util.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='http://localhost:9090/app/dwr/engine.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='http://localhost:9090/app/dwr/interface/ldapService.js'></script><script src='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/custom/organization.js'></script>
```

A line from organization.js

```
treeDiv.dynatree('destroy');
```

I expect no error, because "sometimes" it works, but sometimes gives "'treeDiv.dynatree' is not a function"

In Chromium i can see a link in developer tools> network, and click it and can view source:

```
jquery.dynatree.js?_=1377244144331
```

Comment: Maybe wrong order of javascript

Comment: Silly question: do you load jQuery?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario the problem is about it i think, thanks, i am going to update question

Comment: @tuxi - I'm not sure of what your update means. You only load jQuery in the site's main page, but not in inner pages?

Answer (score 1):

This maybe an issue caused due to **wrong order of placing javascript files**.

Call `jquery.dynatree.js` first then `organization.js` like below.

```
<script
        src='#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.dynatree.js'
        type='text/javascript'></script>

<script src='.../organization.js'type='text/javascript'></script>
```

From your updated question:

"sometimes" it works, but sometimes gives "'treeDiv.dynatree' is not a function"

There maybe an issue caused by some other js files.

Comment: Since you've mentioned sometimes it works, little clarification have included `jQuery` and `jQuery UI`?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your architecture correctly (I'm not sure I do) you have a single-page application located at `main.xhtml`. That application makes use of AJAX to load what appears to be a complete XHTML document and then inserts the HTML in the parent page:

```
$('#main_content').html(data);
```

Whatever JavaScript code such inner page contains that depends on the document load event for initialisation might not work as expected.

For instance, you load `organization.js`, which contains this:

```
treeDiv.dynatree('destroy');
```

... which triggers:

> 'treeDiv.dynatree' is not a function

That means that when that line of code runs the `treeDiv` variable has not been properly initialised.

Comment: Yes this is the architecture. When i add dynatree.js to both inner page and main page, it doesnt work because of double include i think. Thus, isnt there a solution for this architecture?

Comment: @tuxi - I've updated the answer to explain the exact error message you get. You need to ensure that when `treeDiv.dynatree('destroy');` runs the `treeDiv` variable exists.

Comment: `
     <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
     
       <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery-ui.custom.min.js"></script>
     
       <script src="#{applicationBean.resourcePath}/admin/js/jquery.cookie.min.js"></script>`  I pasted all these into organization.xhtml and it works, you were right at first, it is about jQuery libraries. But after a while, it wont work because of double definition.